# Insertar columna al leer archivo excel en java

Tags: java, excel

Llevo un par de dias con este programa, no encuentro la manera de que me imprima correctamente la salida, apenas estoy aprendiendo *java*, disculpen si la pregunta es tonta.

*Mi problema es que quiero insertar una columna entre dos filas,y otro dato al final*, deberia quedar asi:

```
INSERT INTO SALA  (PISO, ESTANTE, TIPO, TITULO, CODIGO, GENERO) VALUES 
(1,'659','49','CUENTOS DE EVA LUNA','SDF585285',FANTASIA),
```

pero me sale esto:

```
INSERT INTO SALA  (PISO, ESTANTE, TIPO, TITULO, CODIGO, GENERO) VALUES 
(1',49,'659',49,'CUENTOS DE EVA LUNA',49,'SDF585285',49,'FANTASIA),
```

Estoy importando  un archivo excel, la importacion sale bien pero a la hora de que quiero ingresar datos que deben ir entre estante y titulo, los imprime en lugares donde no van.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier consejo que me puedan dar.

Este es mi codigo:

```
package readExcel;

import static java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.add;
import jxl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class excel {

    private void leerArchivoExcel(String archivoDestino) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num;
        String tipo;

        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de folio del libro");
         num = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de genero");
         tipo = entrada.nextLine();

        try {
            Workbook archivoExcel = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(archivoDestino));

            for (int sheetNo = 0; sheetNo < archivoExcel.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetNo++) {
                Sheet hoja = archivoExcel.getSheet(sheetNo);
                int numColumnas = hoja.getColumns();
                int numFilas = hoja.getRows();
                int j = 0;
                String data = null;
                System.out.println("\n");
                for (int fila = 0; fila < numFilas; fila++) { 
                    System.out.print("INSERT INTO SALA  (PISO, ESTANTE, TIPO, TITULO, CODIGO, GENERO) VALUES (");
                    for (int columna = 0; columna < numColumnas; columna++) { 

                        data = hoja.getCell(columna, fila).getContents();

                        System.out.print(data);


                        if (j < hoja.getColumns() - 1) {
                            System.out.print("',");
                        }

                        if (j < hoja.getColumns() - 2 ){   
                            System.out.print( num.trim() + ",");
                        }
                    }
                     System.out.print(tipo.trim());
                    System.out.print("),");
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        excel excel = new excel();
        excel.leerArchivoExcel("Libro4.xls");
    }
}
```

Comment: Si los campos que estás recibiendo del Excel, no están en la misma posición que al insertar en la BD, si la posición 3 del Excel se inserta en la 2º de la BD y viceversa, lleva una variable auxiliar y con el contador de la i, cuando sea i=2, intercambia los valores.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero en ningun momento estoy usando una BD, el programa solo me ayudara a generar el script para ahorrar tiempo. Por eso tenia problema. Pero intentare probar tu sugerencia.

Comment: @Lucy Lo que se ve sospechoso es ese extra 49 que siempre aparece por cada columna, es como si .getContents() te estuviera dando ese prefijo o sufijo. 49 también puede ser el número 1 en la hoja de excel, tal vez tengas columnas escondidas en excel?

Comment: @Lucy Puedes poner una fila de la hoja de excel como ejemplo, con todo y los nombres de las columnas? Por ejemplo: ||A|B|C|D||  ||1|659|49|CUENTOS DE EVA LUNA||

Comment: @Lucy No estás incrementando la variable "j", creo que quisiste usar "columna" en vez de "j"

Answer (score 0):

La variable j es cero y no cambia, lo que hace que num.trim() se imprima casi siempre después de cada columna, ve el comentario abajo en el código.

```
package readExcel;

import static java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.add;
import jxl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class excel {

    private void leerArchivoExcel(String archivoDestino) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num;
        String tipo;

        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de folio del libro");
         num = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de genero");
         tipo = entrada.nextLine();

        try {
            Workbook archivoExcel = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(archivoDestino));

            for (int sheetNo = 0; sheetNo < archivoExcel.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetNo++) {
                Sheet hoja = archivoExcel.getSheet(sheetNo);
                int numColumnas = hoja.getColumns();
                int numFilas = hoja.getRows();
                int j = 0;
                String data = null;
                System.out.println("\n");
                for (int fila = 0; fila < numFilas; fila++) { 
                    System.out.print("INSERT INTO SALA  (PISO, ESTANTE, TIPO, TITULO, CODIGO, GENERO) VALUES (");
                    for (int columna = 0; columna < numColumnas; columna++) { 

                        data = hoja.getCell(columna, fila).getContents();

                        System.out.print(data);


                        if (j < hoja.getColumns() - 1) {
                            System.out.print("',");
                        }
// j es cero y no cambia, lo que hace que num.trim() se imprima casi siempre.
                        if (j < hoja.getColumns() - 2 ){   
                            System.out.print( num.trim() + ",");
                        }
                    }
                     System.out.print(tipo.trim());
                    System.out.print("),");
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        excel excel = new excel();
        excel.leerArchivoExcel("Libro4.xls");
    }
}
```